# Hosting provider claims normal use of CiviCRM is "brute force attack"

Tags: joomla, configuration, hosting

In using CiviCRM on a shared server with a local hosting provider, my IP address continually gets blocked by the server's security script. According to my provider my [legitimate CiviCRM] activity is seen as a Brute Force attack on the server.

My question: is this a problem related to the host, or is it related to some misconfiguration of my CiviCRM or Joomla CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds a bit like a problem with mod_security, see also

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36028.0

I have also asked a hoster once of one of my clients to switch it off for that site.
But this forum topic even gives options about how to configure mod_security rules to keep it switched on and still have CiviCRM working.